# How can I list the ingresses that act on a Kubernetes service?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I'd like to retrieve all of the ingresses that act on a Kubernetes service.

I can get the ingresses in a namespace with the command `kubectl get ingress -n <namespace>`.

Is there a command in kubectl that lets me fetch the ingresses that act on a specific Kubernetes service?

Answer (score 12):

To get all ingress rules in the cluster, you can run:

```
kubectl get ingress -A
```

To get a summary of all ingress rules (including their used services), you can run this:

```
kubectl describe ingress -A
```

To get the full ingress objects but in json format, you can run this:

```
kubectl get ingress -A -o json
```

You could then parse that json to get the used services.

Answer (score 6):

You can list all your ingress objects along with their corresponding services like so:

```
> kubectl get ing -o=custom-columns='NAME:.metadata.name,SVCs:..service.name'

NAME           SVCs
my-ingress     my-products,my-discounted-products
my-ingress2    my-products,my-discounted-products
my-ingress3    my-products,my-discounted-products
my-ingress4    my-products11,my-discounted-products
my-ingress5    my-products22,my-discounted-products
neg-demo-ing   neg-demo-svc
```

if you want to filter out and only get the list of ingress objects, for a given service name, here is what you can do (will need to have jq installed):

```
> kubectl get ing -o=json | jq '.items[] | select(..|.service?.name == "my-products") | .metadata.name'

"my-ingress"
"my-ingress2"
"my-ingress3"
```

```
> kubectl get ing -o=json | jq '.items[] | select(..|.service?.name == "neg-demo-svc") | .metadata.name'

"neg-demo-ing"
```

I was looking for a way to achieve the same without additional dependencies with only `jsonpath`, but it seems it isn't possible to do the recursive descent inside the filter.

Answer (score 4):

You have some options...

First list all based in a namespace

```
kubectl get ingress --namespace=<name-space-here>
```

Then describe a specific ingress

```
kubectl describe ingress <ingress-name-here> --namespace=<name-space-here>
```

Another helpful command is list all ingress to the cluster

```
kubectl get ingress -A
```

Tip, you can always use --help for more detailed information about the command. Is very useful

```
kubectl describe --help
```

Good luck :D

Answer (score 3):

There's no command in kubectl, but you can script around it (Bash):

```sh
kubectl get ingress --all-namespaces -o custom-columns=:.metadata.namespace,:.metadata.name --no-headers | while read line; do
  namespace=$(awk '{print $1}' <<<"$line")
  name=$(awk '{print $2}' <<<"$line")
  if kubectl get ingress "$name" -n "$namespace" -o yaml | grep -n " name: $SERVICE"; then
    echo "$namespace/$name"
  fi
done
```

It's not perfect, as this would detect every Ingress with a line matching `name: $SERVICE` (where `$SERVICE` is the name of your Service), thus there might be false positives. However, it should detect all the Ingresses in your cluster that act on your specified Service.